# getting Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Function

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver

ok i am using
eclipse neon 
Client-combined-3.1.0-nodeps.jar 
for firefox-setup 39.0

and this is my code

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class T1 {

    public static void main(String[] args){


    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);


    driver.navigate().to("https://www.orbitz.com/");

    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='primary-header-hotel']")).click();


    String result = driver.getPageSource();

    System.out.println("result is "+" "+ result);

    driver.close();
}

}
```

and this is the error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/google/common/base/Function   at T1.main(T1.java:12) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.base.Function     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   ... 1 more

i have seen a solution to add path for guava-21.0

but more error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path
>   to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver
>   system property; for more information, see
>   https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver. The latest version can be
>   downloaded from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases   at
>   com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:738)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:111)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService.access$100(GeckoDriverService.java:38)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(GeckoDriverService.java:112)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:302)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.createCommandExecutor(FirefoxDriver.java:312)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:272)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:267)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:263)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:122)
>     at T1.main(T1.java:12)

after adding line of code and still Client-combined-3.1.0-nodeps.jar 
firefox 52.0.1   and using geckodriver-v0.15.0-win64
and still getting the same error

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;



public class T1 {

    public static void main(String[] args){

    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Users\\ahmed\\Desktop\\geckodriver.exe"); 
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);


    driver.navigate().to("https://www.orbitz.com/");

    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='primary-header-hotel']")).click();


    String result = driver.getPageSource();

    System.out.println("result is "+" "+ result);

    driver.close();
}

}
```

here is the error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/google/common/base/Function   at T1.main(T1.java:14) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.base.Function     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   ... 1 more

Answer (score 0):

In Selenium 3.1.0 you have to do the following to initialize the gecko driver:

System.setproperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\geckodriver_location\\geckodriver.exe");

Webdriver driver = new Firefoxdriver();

Run your code. It should be success. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: there is a missing quote at the end and no it didnt work still the same error

Comment: Guess your Firefox is not updated. Can you install the latest released version of Firefox & gecko and crosscheck?

Comment: Did it work for you now? Let me know if any other issue.

Comment: it didnt work i updated firefox and download the  gecko correctly changed the location to point to the file and still the same error

Comment: I assume you are using all the released version of Firefox  browser & gecko driver. Can you update your current code & the exact error message

Comment: Which version of jdk/jre are you using ? Check if you are using the updated version or not.

Comment: using jre1.8.0_121

Comment: Check if the path is added in your system Path, classpath, java_home

Comment: already added if i just could post a pic to show you  but i cant cuz of reputation i guess

Comment: Do 2 things : 1. Go to command prompt. 2. Check Java -version 3. Javac version 3. Jre version & update me

Comment: java version "1.8.0_121"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)

Comment: Check if your Mozilla browser & gecko both are either 32 or 64 bit

Comment: the thing is someone suggested to downgrade firefoxe to 39.0 this stable version in order to work  correctly with selenium web driver version and for gecko i already downloaded geckodriver-v0.15.0-win64 it

Comment: Great go ahead. Had it been my day time I could have helped you my own configuration. But unfortunately I am trying to help you through dialogs from my cell phone.